# Google Calendar iframe Embed - Calendar Id to src translation?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have an application which uses Google's Calendar API to create, edit, and cancel appointments. I additionally use Google's iframe embedding to display the calendars.

I am trying to automate the creation of the `iframe` `src` value, so I can allow users to edit which calendars will be displayed and which color to use.

If I used Google's Settings, , Customize interface to create an embeddable iframe, I see that it generates an `iframe` with multiple `src` attributes which correspond to selected sub-calendars.

They look like some sort of base64 encoded string (not real values):

```
&src=YWRkcmVzc2Jvb2656jY29udGFjdHNAZ3JvdX54i5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29t
&src=ZW4udXNhI2hvbG46XlAZ3JvdXAu77i5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29t
```

However, when I use Google's API to pull the calendar Ids, they look like this:

```
c_63orqu43gib0VN3mv75np2278o@group.calendar.google.com
c_80shch9kjkkPGpgl2o9mlt31k8@group.calendar.google.com
```

I want to be able to compare the currently populated `src` values and compare them against what is in the API.  How are the ones from Google's Customize interface encoded? How can I translate the API values into the `iframe` values or vica versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was posting my question, I had a bit of a "duh" moment. The `src` query parameters not only LOOK like base64 encoded values, they ARE base64 encoded values. It turns out that doing a simple base64 encode allows me to translate a `calendarId` into the `src` and a decode will turn the `src` into a `calendarId`.

In PHP:

```php
$calendarId = base64_decode($src);
$src = base64_encode($calendarId);
```

In JavaScript:

```js
let calendarId = atob(src);
let src = btoa(calendarId);
```

I was unable to find any documentation from Google which detailed this and, even knowing it used base64, I couldn't find any references on the web.  Hope this helps someone.